# Is it a foul when the ball pushes the net into blockers hands?

Tags: rules, beach-volleyball

In case of beach volleyball, I am spiking the ball and it hits the net. The hit pushes the net and it touches the blockers hands. Would it be called a foul or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [FIVB Official Beach Volleyball Rules 2017-2020](http://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/Documents/FIVB-BeachVolleyball_Rules_2017-2020-EN-v05.pdf),

> 11.3 CONTACT WITH THE NET
>
> 11.3.3 When the ball is driven into the net, causing it to touch an opponent,
> no fault is committed.

Which clearly state it will not be called fault.

Comment: so does the game continue as usual then?

Comment: @eddyP23 Yes it would continue as usual.